# Find multiple values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a first sheet

```
client  ca
11112   3
11133   445
33333   6
333 666
```

And a second sheet

```
client  Amount 
11112   12
11133   22222
33333   456
333 234
11112   44
11112   78666
11133   6649
11133   43438
```

I need to find client code in the sheet2 and add sum(Amount) in sheet 1

What I have try

```
 nomClient = Range("B" & i).Value
Set cel = Cells.Find(What:=nomClient, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

My problen is Find can't do a sum , how to modify it ?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: do you have to use VBA? If not, you could do it with SUMIFS formula.

Comment: or the old fashioned pivot :)

Comment: Along with VLOOKUP...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use this function:

```
Function GetSum(nomClient As String)
    With Worksheets("secondSheetName") '<--| change "secondSheetName" to your actual second sheet name
        GetSum = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(.Columns(1), nomClient, .Columns(2)) '<--| change (1) and (2) to your actual correspondent "client" and "Amount" columns index in your second sheet
    End With
End Function
```

to be exploited as follows

```
nomClient = Worksheets("firstSheetName").Range("B" & i).Value ''<--| change "firstSheetName" to your actual first sheet name

MsgBox GetSum(nomClient)
```